# How do you change multiple numbers in a single JLabel?

Tags: java, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JButton named `btnUp`, as well as a JLabel named `lblCount`.
`lblCount`'s Text property is "0/10".

When I click btnUp, I would like to increase the label's numerator by 1, and decrease its denominator by 1 so it shows "1/9", all the way up to "10/0".

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You'd ... change the text on the `JLabel` with `setText()`.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.

Comment: Oh no, trust me, I understood it perfectly.

Comment: Then why did you make such a vague comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't stop at "10/0".  I'm sure you can figure that part out on your own.

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("0/10");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] parts = label.getText().split("/");
                int left = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]) + 1;
                int right = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]) - 1;
                label.setText(left + "/" + right);
            }
        });

        pane.add(button);
        pane.add(label);


        frame.add(pane);
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


}
```